# Order by association count, group with join but include none? FULL OUTER JOIN?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, join

I'm looking to display a list of all users ordered by the number of associaiated posts.

`user has_many :posts`

`posts belong_to :user`

This query from another SO question got me correctly ordered results, but it does not return any users who do not have any posts because of the inner join.

`User.joins(:posts).group('posts.user_id').order('count(posts.user_id) desc')`

Is there any way to get a relation back with ALL of the users, highest posts first and nil(0) posts last? I tried the following but I get back a large number `user_id: nil, first_name: nil, etc` user entries. It seems that users that have 0 posts in the following query get returned as a relation element with all values set to `nil`?

`User.joins('FULL OUTER JOIN posts ON posts.user_id = users.id').group('posts.user_id', 'users.id').order('count(posts.user_id) DESC')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a `LEFT` join from the `users` table.  This will make sure that if you happen to have `posts` that aren't connected to any `users`, they won't be included.  But you will still get back the set of `users` that don't have any `posts`.

Then you will want to just group by the `users.id` to make sure you get back one row per `User`.

Finally, we'll want to count the distinct occurrences of `Post` rows.  This will make sure we keep the correct count, even if we start joining with other tables.

You should be able to use something like this:

```
User.joins("LEFT JOIN posts ON users.id = posts.user_id").group("users.id").order("COUNT(DISTINCT posts.id) DESC")
```

And if you want to display the `posts` count for each `User`, you can include that in the select with something like:

```
User.select("users.*, COUNT(DISTINCT posts.id) AS posts_count").joins("LEFT JOIN posts ON users.id = posts.user_id").group("users.id").order("COUNT(DISTINCT posts.id) DESC").each do |user|
  puts user.posts_count
end
```

Comment: Will check when I get back to my desk, but looks perfect for what I need. Thanks!

Comment: Works like a charm, but leads to another problem. I have a `default_scope` on `Topics` that removes those older than 1 month ago. I would like to inner join this table with `default_scope` but when I do the order gets rearranged. It's still close, users with high post counts are still at the top, but it's not exact order anymore. `posts.count` is like `8, 12, 21, 7` and 0's are all at the end. The fully query looks like `User.joins(:topics).joins("LEFT JOIN subscriptions ON users.id = posts.user_id").group("users.id").order("count(posts.user_id) DESC")`

Comment: What is the code in the `Topic` `default_scope`?  And what does the SQL output look like in the console when you do the query you've noted in your comment?

Comment: `default_scope -> { where(arel_table[:release].gt 1.month.ago).order(:release) }`

The output is 
`SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "topics" ON "topics"."user_id" = "users"."id" AND ("topics"."release" > '2014-09-01 01:28:08.655984') LEFT JOIN posts ON users.id = posts.user_id GROUP BY users.id  ORDER BY count(posts.user_id) DESC`

Comment: Hm.  I'm not immediately seeing what would cause a problem with the ordering.  One thing to try to make sure the `order(:release)` isn't messing things up behind the scenes: `User.joins(:topics).joins("LEFT JOIN subscriptions ON users.id = posts.user_id").where(["topics.release > ?", 1.month.ago]).group("users.id").order("count(posts.user_id) DESC")`

Comment: Removed and still incorrect ordering, even if I remove the `default_scope` all together. I also tried adding a counter cache for posts and `order('posts_count DESC')` which keeps the order correctly, so it seems that it must be something in the `LEFT JOIN` query combined with the `INNER JOIN` on `Topic`, but most other code is completely removed now, so I'm not sure what could cause this?

Comment: Oh, and while `counter_cache` column would work ideally, I can't use it in this case because I'm also adding multi-tenancy to the mix, and I want recent active posting users per tenant. Users can and should join multiple tenants in my design, so I can't just use overall `posts_count`. Sort of like stack-overflow with seperate reputation for each community.

Comment: Now that we're joining the additional table, it's illustrating a limitation in the original answer--it only works when we are joining two tables.  I've updated the answer now to count distinct occurrences of the join table we care about.

Comment: Perfect! I wish I could give more rate ups. Thanks for sticking through. I need to learn more about SQL in general it seems, I understand the basics through rails but trying to do more complicated queries gets me scratching my head. Any recommendations?

Comment: I don't have a singular resource to recommend.  I'd suggest playing around in the query tool within the admin program for whichever database you are using.  Keep digging into online documentation whenever you've got a fun problem to solve.  I'm always learning more SQL tricks myself.